# c# Can't select nuint framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

I am trying to use NUnit for TDD. I have installed all the NUnit packages, but when I go to create a new unit test, I am unable to select NUnit as my Test Framework... The only option is MSTest...

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I am new to c# and Visual Studio so all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can create a class library project and add NUnit as nuget package reference. The Test Framework drop down does not have any other options?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Nope, no other options in the drop down... I navigated the "Get Additional Extensions" link too.

Comment: @datainc Take a look at this page: [Introduction To NUnit Testing Framework](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-nunit-testing-framework/) - It might help you to setup/run the NUnit tests

Comment: Check following reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit - it is related to unit testing C# with NUnit and .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one or both, (I added them at the same time so I don't know which one fixed the problem.) of these extensions.

TestGenerator NUnit Extensions

Nunit VS Tempaltes